# How to create a column with the datatype float which only stores up to 3 decimals in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to create a table in my PostgreSQL:

```
CREATE TABLE my_table(
    id INT GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    description TEXT,
    score FLOAT NOT NULL
);
```

How do I limit the number of decimals stored in the "score" column to a maximum of 3 decimals?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would use [`numeric`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-NUMERIC-DECIMAL).  However, you need a *precision* as well, which limits the maximum value:

```
CREATE TABLE my_table(
    id INT GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    description TEXT,
    score NUMERIC(10, 3) NOT NULL
);
```

This will store numbers up to 9,999,999.999.